# Ubuntu dotnet user-secrets

Tags: dotnet-cli, .net-core

I installed dotent core on Ubuntu v16.04. Problem is when I try to use `dotnet user-secrets` it says:
`No executable found matching command "dotnet-user-secrets"`

dotnet core version:
`1.0.0-preview2-003131`

dotnet screenshot:[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the Secret Manager in .NET Core, you will have to install it to the project:

1. Add the line `Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools` to the `tools` section of your `project.json`
2. Run `dotnet restore`

You can find more information about it in the [official .NET documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/app-secrets.html#installing-the-secret-manager-tool).

Comment: Is this still valid for .net core 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

When I added that package through nuget it added it to the "dependencies" section. So I had to move the line below:

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
```

out of the "dependencies" section and into the "tools" section in the project.json file. Then I ran dotnet restore and then it worked. Just make sure you run those commands on the same directory where project.json file is located.